# Angular service that converts camel case strings to hyphenated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that Angular converts directive names from camel case to hyphen separated strings.

Is this functionality accessible through the API, like a function or something? 
I would like to convert some strings to hyphenated versions in my angular app and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if not necessary.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/17990864/angular-directive-name-only-lower-case-letters-allowed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function used can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.10/src/Angular.js#L1447-L1453)

Unfortunately, it is not available through API.

[lodash](http://www.lodash.com) has method [kebabCase](https://lodash.com/docs#kebabCase) that does exactly this.

Comment: You can go back the other way with `_.camelCase()` too https://lodash.com/docs#camelCase

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code to convert the Camelcase string into directive name format.

```
myApp.filter(`con2directivename`,function(){
   return function(name){
        return name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();});
    };
});
```

Comment: FYI: this returns `'-hello-world'` for an input of `'HelloWorld'`: `function con2directivename(name) { return name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();}); } con2directivename('HelloWorld');`